# Laravel Where Count > N

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have 2 models in my app:

**1. Customer.php**

**2. Car.php**

Now I would like to run a query that returns all customers that have less than 2 cars. Where 2 is a number that can be changed by the user.

I have tried this but it didn't work, it just returns all customer records:

```
$customers = Customer::whereHas("cars", function($query) {
    $query->selectRaw("count(*) < ?", [2]);
})
->get();
```

**Edit:**
The two models are linked in a pivot table, meaning A customer can have more than 1 car and a Car can belong to more than 1 customer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use this:

```
$customers = Customer::withCount('cars')
    ->having('cars_count', '<', 2)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Actually this works now, didn't work before because my relation wasn't setup correctly.

Comment: This only works if the query was grouped by, otherwise it throws `unknown column cars_count`.

Comment: And how do you group by the query? This answer is incomplete, it doesn't work as is

Comment: 'cars_count' alias is already created by the 'withCount' function
@Ken

Answer (score 5):

So , here is the result.

Relation in model `Customer.php`

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car','car_customer','car_id','customer_id');
}
```

Query to get all customers with N cars:

```
 $userInput = 2;
 $data = Customer::with('cars')
                ->withCount('cars')
                ->has('cars', '<', $userInput)
                ->orderBy('cars_count', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Where the **$userInput** is your 'N'.

Comment: This will work, but Jonas' solution is strictly better since this one executes 1 more subquery.

Comment: Jonas' soution will say that there is no column 'cars_count'

Comment: Not if the relation is set up correctly. If it isn't this won't work either. Also, why would you expect `->orderBy('cars_count')` to work if there's no column `cars_count`? As for the explanation, `->withCount('cars')` adds a `cars_count` to the select. It makes a subquery that counts the relation.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, @devk was right, Jonas's answer didn't work for me initially since my relations were not setup correctly, thanks for your help o/

Comment: @user3718908 ,**whereHas()** is the same as **has()** , but **whereHas()** allows to specify additional filters on related model , **has()** filters selecting model based on a relation.

Comment: @DevK what do you mean by if the relation is 'set up correctly'?  Mine is a simple `belongsToMany` and I am getting the 'undefined column` error.  Query looks like `Group::withCount('users')->having('users_count', '<', '2')->get();`

Comment: Note that both withCount() and has() insert the same subquery into the sql and so it is run twice. `withCount()` adds as an alias select: `select (select count(*) ...) as cars_count`. And `has()` adds as where: `where (select count(*) ...) < N`. I would only use `has()` to prevent double sql evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way:

```
$customers = Customer::has('cars','<', 2)->get();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please explain why this is the best solution in your opinion.

Comment: Because its simple , one line code and  you don`t have to load any relation or using "having" query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

```
$input = 2;
$customers = Customer::whereHas("cars", function($query) use ($input) {
    $query->where(DB::raw("count(cars.id)"), "<", DB::raw($input))
})->get();
```

Comment: No I haven't, I forgot to add that Customer's and Cars are joined on a pivot table.

Comment: Please , provide a **sqlfiddle**.

Comment: It's just a belongsToMany relation.  Meaning I have a customer_car pivot table in my database.

Comment: I know. But i need to write that query in raw sql , so i can write that query in laravel.

Comment: Please add some 3-4 rows for each table.