# How can write this query with laravel query builder?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `orders` and `ordered_items`

orders

```
Id | quantity
```

ordered_items

```
order_id | product_id
```

I wanted to query all the orders which have order quantity equals to ordered_items count.

I can do this with raw query, but I wanted to write this query with laravel query builder. How can I achieve this.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE quantity = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ordered_items
    WHERE ordered_items.order_id = orders.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Relational Query

In your orders Model

```
public function orderedItems(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderedItem::class);
}
```

In your OrderedItem Model

```
public function order(){

    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);

}
```

In your controller Equivalent code here

```
$order = Order::find($id);
$order->orderedItems()->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like:

```
$values=DB::table('orders')->where('orders.quantity','=',
DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ordered_items WHERE ordered_items.order_id = orders.ID"))->get();
```

or using join sub query way [join sub query way](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins):

> SELECT * FROM orders WHERE quantity = ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM
> ordered_items WHERE ordered_items.order_id = orders.ID)

you can break this into two pieces ...

```
$ordered_items_counts=DB::table('ordered_items')->selectRaw('order_id,count(*) as orders_count')->groupBy('order_id');

$values=DB::table('orders')->joinSub($ordered_items_counts,'ordered_items_counts',function($join){
$join->on('orders.id', '=', 'ordered_items_count.order_id');
})->whereRaw('ordered_items_counts.orders_count=orders.quantity')->get();
```

if you have models with correct relations, things should be easier:

```
$values = Order::withCount('orderedItems')
    ->havingRaw('orderedItems_count=quantity')
    ->get();
```

Comment: $values = Order::withCount('orderedItems')
    ->havingRaw('orderedItems_count=quantity')
    ->get(); I wanted to do this way, I think needs to bind on subquery as orderd_items_count column will not be found while comparing with quantity

Comment: please take a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081666/10573560

Comment: this column is auto generated: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: it might be: orderedItems_count, or ordered_Items_count according to your relation name ...