# scope Model on relation sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope, relationship

I am trying to create a scope in the User model for users who their related transactions total more than $x. I can't seem to get it. I tried the following:

```
return $query->withCount(['transactions as total' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as total'))->where('total', '>', $x);
        }]);
```

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081666/6472849

Comment: `function($query) use ($x) {` You are missing to include (use) `$x` in inner scope.